# MVC HTML Helper, get parent view of current partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am writing an Html extension to render partial views dynamically (view name/path is provided by CMS at runtime).

Within my extension I need to determine the name or path to the outermost view containing the partial in the case where a view contains a partial contains another partial contains yet another partial- I need to learn the identity of the parent view.

Within the extension method I know I can get the immediate parent through the HtmlHelper.ViewDataContainer property.  That tells me the context of the the currently executing extension. What I need to be able to do is iterate up to its parent view if there is one.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: Because I do. Why are you asking?

Comment: To try to understand what you are trying to do, so i can help you. ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search for `controller` and `action`, you can get it like so:

```
string action = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
string controller = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
string url = "~/" + controller + "/" + action;
```

To get the immediate view (including partial), it is like so:

```
var webPage = HtmlHelper.ViewDataContainer as WebPageBase;
var virtualPath = webPage.VirtualPath;
```

To get the first view path (the master view containing all partial views):

```
var viewPath = ((System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView)(htmlHelper.ViewContext.View)).ViewPath;
```

Comment: Right thanks, I mentioned in the OP that I know how to get at the immediate parent as well as the controller/action as you have demonstrated.  What I was trying to learn was the name of the view containing the topmost partial in cases where partials contain partials, the action doesn't do it as it can invoke many different views depending on circumstances.

Comment: i have added a new info to get the first view Path, not the immediate partial, but the view called by the controller action. Now with this, you can read the text inside the view, then find all Html.Partial("SomeName"). The only thing i can imagine to find all partialView is to make your own Html.Partial or create a view Engine (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294297/Creating-your-own-MVC-View-Engine-into-MVC-Applica) and create your own Hierarchy list of view/PartialView

Comment: It will be more easy for me if i know why you need this values. If it's for your web app or you creating a plugin for other projects.

Comment: Thank you, the last bit where you extract the ViewPath I think will work for now, until we get more complicated nested partials.  I think you are right I am looking at a custom view engine.  I need the view names b/c we are creating string resources in a separate utility (like a CMS), the id's of the strings are built by concatenating each view that the value resides in, e.g. ParentView_Partial1_Partial2_ResourceName_UniqueId

Comment: can you mark it as answered if it help you please :)
Tanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered and it's over a year old, but would using ViewData to pass the view names down from the top to the furthest nested partial view work? So in the ParentView you'd do something like:

```
@{
    ViewData["ResourcePath"] = "ParentView";
    Html.RenderPartial("Partial1", Model, ViewData);
}
```

And then in your Partial1 view:

```
@{
    ViewData["ResourcePath"] = ViewData["ResourcePath"] + "_Partial1";
    Html.RenderPartial("Partial2", Model, ViewData);
}
```

And so on until you reach the level where you need to get the string resource.